# How to Upgrade project from Jsf 2.2 to Jsf 2.3 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, websocket, wildfly, jsf-2.3

Currently I am working on project using `Primefaces 6.1` and `Jsf 2.2` using Eclipse. Now I want to upgrade project from `Jsf 2.2` to `Jsf 2.3`. But I am facing some issues after replacing Jsf's jar files with `javax.faces-2.3.2.jar`, `javax.faces-api-2.3.jar` , `jsf-impl-2.2.3.jar`.

I know this issue is already raised in [Issues using Websocket in Jsf 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634633/fwebsocket-tag-library-supports-namespace-http-xmlns-jcp-org-jsf-core-but) but here in my case, all jar files/ libraries are already added. And my question is:
**Which Editor is currently available for `Jsf 2.3` support?** 
I think Eclipse is supporting till `jsf 2.2` only

**Issues:**
1. Eclipse is unable to recognize new Tags like 
2. After running project, I am getting error message

```
14:41:37,978 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-10) UT005023: Exception handling request to /haag/user/push.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: /user/push.xhtml @21,63 <f:websocket> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: websocket
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /user/push.xhtml @21,63 <f:websocket> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: websocket
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:311)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:268)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:498)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:180)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:811)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:275)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1653)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:875)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:798)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1198)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:564)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:298)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:464)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:440)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:481)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:63)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:295)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1000)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: 1:  no idea, 2: you either did not package your own jsf libs correctly (why do you btw, wildfly has a release that contains jsf 2.3) or did not configure your server to use the jsf libs you provide instead of the built in ones.

Comment: @Kukeltje I actually replaced only 3 jar files by these `javax.faces-2.3.2.jar`,`javax.faces-api-2.3.jar` , `jsf-impl-2.2.3.jar`.  And I don't know if there is need for any other replacement! Can you please help me? And wildfly is a kind of replacement for tomcat, right?

Comment: 3 jars is wrong, I think #1 is #2+#3 and _"And wildfly is a kind of replacement for tomcat, right?"_ can be easily googled... Wildfly contains these jars already if you run JavaEE 8 in a recent version of wildfly (also googleable) But maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info first

Comment: _"And wildfly is a kind of replacement for tomcat, right?"_ .... no, definitely not. Wildfly replaces JBoss.

Comment: [1] See [Eclipse Bug 532336 - Add support for JSF 2.3](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532336). That bug has been reopened, which looks ominous. [2] Post **web.xml** if you have one; regardless of other issues you probably need to change its dtd(s). [3] Your issue #1 (_"Eclipse is unable to recognize new Tags like"_) has no ending! Which tags are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct. It takes some time for Eclipse to implement new features. Using the latest Red Hat Developer Studio, which is based on Eclipse, I have the same issue, it still doesn't recognise the new websocket tag in Eclipse, but you can use it in your project. I'm also using JSF 2.3 in my project. Log an issue at Eclipse if you want to speed up the process.
2. The error is related to your server. I guess you use WildFly or EAP, based on your logs.

To solve this:

- follow this guide: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JSF+Configuration#JSFConfiguration-ConfiguringaJSFapptouseanondefaultJSFimplementation
- and this guide for splitting the jars: [How to install one jar variant of JSF (javax.faces.jar) on WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899887/how-to-install-one-jar-variant-of-jsf-javax-faces-jar-on-wildfly)

Very important: if you don't configure your wildfly or your application to explicitly use 2.3, it still won't work.

On server level through CLI: `/subsystem=jsf/:write-attribute(name=default-jsf-impl-slot,value=<JSF_IMPL_NAME>-<JSF_VERSION>)`

On application level through web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.JSF_CONFIG_NAME</param-name>
  <param-value>myfaces-2.2.12</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Good luck